# Best way to find image resolution

Tags: django

I have a standard image model.

```
class ImageUpload(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/%Y/%m/%d')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

However, when I created the model, I did not make fields for height and width.  Is there anyway for me to find the height and width of the image in the view without adding anything to the model?  If not, how could I go about adding the height and width fields to the model and have it auto add from the images already stored in the database?

Comment: Do you have a particular image format?  Are you opposed to using PIL or pillow?

Comment: I already have PIL installed, and the image format depends on the upload.

Answer (score 4):

Or you could use django `get_image_dimensions`:

```
from django.core.files.images import get_image_dimensions

w, h = get_image_dimensions(image) # Returns the (width, height) of an image, given an open file or a path
```

Answer (score 2):

For newly uploaded images, handle it in your post_save of your model using a signal:

```
django.db.models.signals.post_save
```

To get the size, using PIL,

```
img = Image.open(path_to_file)
width, height = img.size
```

For existing images, you probably want to just script something to do this for existing database entries.

The alternative to scripting something would be to update your application to try to find the width, height and update them if they are not already set.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PIL(Python Image Library) for this:

```
from PIL import Image
img_file = Image.open(path_to_imagefile)
w,h = img_file.size
```