# django image resolution in FileField

Tags: python, django, filefield

I have a class

```
class MyFiles(models.Model):
    my_file = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.my_file.url
```

In my view i have a query like:

```
read_file = MyFiles.objects.all()
```

In my template I want to show their resolution. Somewhere I saw I can do `{{read_file.height}} {{read_file.width}}`

But its now working for me .. How can I get the resolution of image using FileField ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17515977/best-way-to-find-image-resolution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't use `{{read_file.height}}` and `{{read_file.width}}` in current model, because read_file is an queryset and not an instance of model!

Secondly: width and height are available only in `ImageField`, so proper solution will be:

1. replace FileField with ImageField
2. iterate through `read_file` in your template or fetch only one object using get in view
3. Use `width` and `height` on field. Example template code:

   ```
   {% for file in read_file %}
       {{ file.my_file.width }}x{{ file.my_file.height }}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   That will give You proper results.